# How to check array contains in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Using MongoDB and I've collection contains array of data,

```
    "provinces" : [ 
    {
        "province" : "central",
        "provincesTypes" : [ 
            {
                "prices" : {
                    "week" : {
                        "hourly" : 500
                    }
                },
                "location" : "nature"
            }
```

How do I do these searches,

- get provinces ---> province --> value
- get provinces ---> provincesTypes --> prices --> week --> hourly value
- get provinces ---> provincesTypes --> location value

Comment: Let us know what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Use the dot operator. For example, if you wanna check if the hourly is higher than 400, you can do the following:

`db.provinces.find({"provinces.province.provinceTypes.prices.week.hourly" : {$gt:400}})`

Hope my answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want result with all 3 conditions apply, for that you have to query like:

```
 db.provinces.find({"provinces.province":"value",
"provinces.provinceTypes":{
$elemMatch:{"prices.week.hourly":{$gt:400},"location":"value"}}})
```

try this.